# Posting Dynamic Field data Back to View in Cakephp

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, cakephp, dynamic

I'm working on a system for a non profit organization at school, I need to post the data  from the dynamic fields back to the view if there are validation errors. Below is the code that creates the dynamic fields.

-This is the jquery function

```
var lastRow=0;

function addPerson() {
    lastRow++;
    $("#victimsTable tbody>tr:#victim0").clone(true).attr('id','victim'+lastRow).removeAttr('style').insertBefore("#victimsTable tbody>tr:#trAdd");
    $("#victim"+lastRow+" button").attr('onclick','removePerson('+lastRow+')');
    $("#victim"+lastRow+" input:eq(0)").attr('name','data[Victim]['+lastRow+'][victimId]').attr('id','victimVictimId'+lastRow);
    $("#victim"+lastRow+" input:eq(1)").attr('name','data[Victim]['+lastRow+'][firstName]').attr('id','victimFirstName'+lastRow);
    $("#victim"+lastRow+" input:eq(2)").attr('name','data[Victim]['+lastRow+'][lastName]').attr('id','victimLastName'+lastRow);
    $("#victim"+lastRow+" input:eq(3)").attr('name','data[Victim]['+lastRow+'][dateOfBirth]').attr('id','victimDateOfBirth'+lastRow);
    $("#victim"+lastRow+" select.g").attr('name','data[Victim]['+lastRow+'][gender]').attr('id','victimGender'+lastRow);
    $("#victim"+lastRow+" select.r").attr('name','data[Victim]['+lastRow+'][race]').attr('id','victimRace'+lastRow);
    $("#victim"+lastRow+" input:eq(4)").attr('name','data[Victim]['+lastRow+'][streetAddress]').attr('id','victimStreetAddress'+lastRow);
    $("#victim"+lastRow+" input:eq(5)").attr('name','data[Victim]['+lastRow+'][zipCode]').attr('id','victimZipCode'+lastRow);
    $("#victim"+lastRow+" input:eq(6)").attr('name','data[Victim]['+lastRow+'][city]').attr('id','victimCity'+lastRow);
    $("#victim"+lastRow+" input:eq(7)").attr('name','data[Victim]['+lastRow+'][state]').attr('id','victimState'+lastRow);
    $("#victim"+lastRow+" input:eq(8)").attr('name','data[Victim]['+lastRow+'][email]').attr('id','victimEmail'+lastRow);
    $("#victim"+lastRow+" input:eq(9)").attr('name','data[Victim]['+lastRow+'][phoneOne]').attr('id','victimPhoneOne'+lastRow);
    $("#victim"+lastRow+" select.p1t").attr('name','data[Victim]['+lastRow+'][phoneOneType]').attr('id','victimPhoneOneType'+lastRow);
    $("#victim"+lastRow+" input:eq(10)").attr('name','data[Victim]['+lastRow+'][phoneTwo]').attr('id','victimPhoneTwo'+lastRow);
    $("#victim"+lastRow+" select.p2t").attr('name','data[Victim]['+lastRow+'][phoneTwoType]').attr('id','victimPhoneTwoType'+lastRow);
    AddVictimCalScript(lastRow);
    AddVictimChosenScript(lastRow);
    AddVictimChosenRaceScript(lastRow);
}
function removePerson(x) {
    $("#victim"+x).remove();
}
```

-These are the inputs for the fields

```
<h3>Add Victims</h3>
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table" id="victimsTable">
<tr>
<tr id="victim0" style="display:none;">
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->button('&nbsp;Remove this Victim&nbsp;',array('type'=>'button','title'=>'Click Here to remove this victim','onclick'=>'removePerson()')); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.victimId',array('type'=>'text','id'=>'resultField2')); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.firstName',array('label'=>'First Name')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.lastName',array('label'=>'Last Name')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.dateOfBirth',array('type'=>'text')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.gender',array('class'=>'g','label'=>'Gender','type'=>'select','options'=>array('Unassigned'=>'----','Male' =>'Male','Female'=>'Female'))); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.race',array('class'=>'r','label'=>'Race','type'=>'select','options'=>$race)); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.streetAddress',array('label'=>'Street Address')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.zipCode',array('label'=>'Zip Code')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.city',array('label'=>'City')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.state',array('label'=>'State')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.email',array('label'=>'Email')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.phoneOneType',array('class'=>'p1t','label'=>'Phone One Type','type'=>'select','options'=>$phonetype)); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.phoneOne',array('label'=>'Phone One')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.phoneTwoType',array('class'=>'p2t','label'=>'Phone Two Type','type'=>'select','options'=>$phonetype)); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.phoneTwo',array('label'=>'Phone Two')); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="trAdd"> </tr>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
    <td id="trAdd"> <?php echo $this->Form->button('Add Victim(s)',array('type'=>'button','label'=>'Click Here to add another victim','onclick'=>'addPerson()')); ?> </td>
    <tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
</div>
```

My question is how can I post the data back to view if there are validation errors? The code saves perfectly, but I'm very new to programming in cakephp, ajax and jquery. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$this->Model->save( $data, false);
```

but if you have to ommit the validiation it means that your conception is missed. You should change validiation criteria or change your approach in database.

**Another possibility** is that you have **Security** component in your application. It prevents from working with dynamic forms generated on client side without usage of **jQuery wrapper**. Her is how to do it.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html